# How to get Laravel rows randomly, from filtered rows?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I've got a Laravel model, (Cars). I'd like to get 4 random cars, but only picking these 4 random cars from a subset of the top 10 cars, as ranked by their 'score_total'

I've tried the code below, but the inRandomOrder doesn't seem to have any effect. Any advice would be much appreciated. I'm on Laravel 5.4.

```
Cars::orderBy('score_total','DESC')->take(10)->inRandomOrder()->take(4)->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `random` instead :

```
$cars = Cars::orderBy('score_total','DESC')->take(10)->get();
$random =  $cars->random(4);
```